# Problem with this "Windows and Safari function"

Tags: javascript, windows, safari

I'd like to run some js code only if I'm on Safari on Windows.
'Alert' works but any other code (like `body.classList` ... etc) doesn't work. Why? 
Thank you very much for any help

```
var safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var windows = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win")!=-1);
var body = document.body;

if (safari && windows) {
  alert('this is safari on windows'); //This works
  body.classList.add("safwin"); //This not works
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that the class `safwin` isn't being added to the body? Did you inspect element?

Comment: Exactly, I tried to add classes to different html elements but the inspector doesn't show them

Comment: Did you inspect element after you closed the alert popup? When the alert pops up it will freeze any code proceeding it only until you've closed the alert box. From my testing, your code seems to be adding the class

Comment: how did you do it?
Actually gives me error "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'body.classList')" Where am I wrong? (I have no other scripts except this one)

Comment: Does it work if you wrap your code in a load event listener: `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // your code here...
  console.log(document.body);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the `document` isn't ready yet when your javascript fires, and so `document.body` will give you `null`. In order to access the `document` you'll need to execute your code when the *document object model* (DOM) has loaded. You can do this by adding an event listener to your `window` such that you run your code when the *DOM* has loaded (using `"DOMContentLoaded"`):

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
  var safari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
  var windows = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win")!=-1);
  var body = document.body; // you can now safely access document.body

  if (safari && windows) {
    alert('this is safari on windows'); // This works
    body.classList.add("safwin"); // This will now work
  }
});
```